# POSIXct and plyrmr

Tags: r, hadoop, posixct

Why do POSIXct objects not work with the plyrmr package? Here is my code:

```
filename2 <- "/user/sgerony/mtcars"
complex.function = function(x){
  as.data.frame(mutate(x,date.time=as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 03:15")))    
}
magic.wand(complex.function)

mtcars %|% complex.function()
```

Result:

```
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb           date.time
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2014-01-01 03:15:00
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2014-01-01 03:15:00
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2014-01-01 03:15:00
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 2014-01-01 03:15:00
```

etc..

```
input(mtcars) %|% complex.function()
```

Result:

```
Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce, combine = combine, vectorized.reduce,  : 
  hadoop streaming failed with error code 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Some packages may or may not support working with date/time. Have you checked what's the status of the `plyrmr` package?

Comment: I was told that this problem is not related to plyrmr: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736415/using-the-magic-wand-function-for-a-block-of-code)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to bypass the POSIxct objects knowing that I do use the 'difftime' & 'weekdays' for example?

Comment: See @piccolbo's advice of creating a string.

Comment: I as wondering: Is the impossibility to have POSIXct types linked to the fact that the HDFS does not have such a data type?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately cols of this type are not supported by `plyrmr`. My answer to your same question elsewhere was incorrect, but there you asked 8 questions in one and here you provide more detail. I would suggest to represent posixct as strings as a workaround and then convert in and out of posixct for time-related operations.